# Getting an IntPtr to a ulong variable in C#

Tags: c#, interop, intptr, istream

I need to pass an IntPtr to IStream.Read, and the IntPtr should point to a ulong variable. How do I get this IntPtr that points to my ulong variable?

Comment: As a side note to people answering this question, he wants a ulong because .NET's IntPtr is 64-bit on x64 systems.

Comment: Well, I need a ulong because IStream.Read needs a IntPtr to a ulong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to change the IStream definition:

```
void Read([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] byte[] pv,
          int cb, /*IntPtr*/ ref int pcbRead);
```

Then you can write

```
int pcbRead = 0;
Read(..., ref pcbRead);
```

Comment: Aftre some thought I realized this was my best option. IStream is after all just an interface. Why not create my own interface...

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to use the GCHandle method if you want to avoid unsafe code. I am not sure on how this works with boxed value types.

```
var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(myVar, GCHandleType.Pinned);
var ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject()
```

Comment: This approached worked. Interestingly I still needed to Marshal.WriteInt64 the value back to my ulong variable (perhapsit was just the debugged that was not smart enough though)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use unsafe code try the following.

```
var myValue = GetTheValue();
var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGLobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ulong));
Marshal.StructureToPointer(ptr, myValue, false);
```

At some point later on, you will need to call Marshal.FreeHGlobal on the "ptr" value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pointer = new IntPtr(&myVariable);
```

Comment: While this does get the pointer, you haven't asked the GC to keep it fixed, so myVariable may be moved and that pointer no longer belongs to you.